# SSRS Expression to Get last 12 months

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a ssrs report and this report display last 12 months data. I have 2 parameters startDate and Enddate. 
The End date is always the current month and I want the start date to be the last 12 months. For example if my (End Date) current month is JAN 2018. I want my start date to be Feb 2017. 
I have below expression but this give me Jan 2017 date for my start date.

=DateAdd("M", -12,Today())

Comment: You've asked it to take 12 months away from `Today()` so it will give you Jan 2017. If you want is based on your parameters, you must use that parameter instead of `Today()` something like `=DateAdd("M", -12, Parameters!EndDate.Value)`

Comment: Thanks Alan for your quick response. Sorry I am new in SSRS is there any way to subtract this based on current month not based on day. like =DateAdd("M", -12,Month())

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and show some examples of what you want to see based on some sample dates. e.g. If today is 2018-01-24 I would expect to get xxx-xx-xx as my start date etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression for the start date parameter default value.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, Parameters!EndDate.Value))
```

Here's what the parameter values would equal:

[image]